# unknown keyword pages while enabling pages to gitlab-ci ,

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have the following in my .gitlab-ci.yml

```
 ---
 test-foo-bar:
    before_script:
      - pwd
      - GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true git clone https://192.168.122.1/foobar/myproj
      - cd myproj
      - ansible-playbook provision.yml -e test_suite_name=test-foo-bar
      - export ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False
      - chmod 0600 ssh_priv_key
   script:
     - ansible-playbook runtest.yml -e test_suite_name=test-foo-bar --tags shared,sssd
   pages:
     script:
       - mkdir .public
       - cp -r * .public
       - mv .public public
   artifacts:
     paths:
       - public
```

I have the above in .gitlab-ci.yml and when i run ci lint, 
it give error:

```
Error: jobs:test-foo-bar config contains unknown keys: pages
```

Any hints as to how to resolve the issue. our gitlab instance does support pages and has a lot of static html page already hosted.

Answer (score 0):

That error message was introduced in [commit 7cef4f1](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/commit/7cef4f1908d99743bf1dfb9c1cfdd6b2936b2b3d)

Check if your `gitlab-ci.yml` uses [`pages` as documented](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#pages): for a [job entry](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/7cef4f1908d99743bf1dfb9c1cfdd6b2936b2b3d/lib/gitlab/ci/config/node/job.rb), I don't see `pages` listed.
For instance, keep in mind [projects in subgroup don't support pages](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/34864) anyway.